# Move camera with arrow keys in C&C Generals: Zero Hour

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals, command-and-conquer-zero-hour

I own C&C Generals and C&C Generals: Zero Hour through Origin.

It is totally possible to move the camera with the keyboard's arrow keys in standard Generals but not in Zero Hour. In Zero Hour the arrow keys are used to cycle through your units.

Is there any way, I can change that behaviour to the standard Generals style?

Comment: I found this old thread where the problem is, weirdly enough, the exact opposite: http://www.cnclabs.com/forums/cnc_postst6210_Generals---Keyboard-Controls--arrow-keys.aspx.

Comment: That is really weird. But I will try to fiddle with the ini files. That seems to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the hotkeys without any external software. The hotkey files are located inside the ".big" files, that are in your C&C folder.

There is a developer who created a tool called MCCMixer and made a tutorial on YouTube. He explains everything from start to finish. I changed all my hotkeys (including the camera hotkeys, because I don't want them at all - so I disabled them) as I wanted. Here is the link to the Tutorial:

I recommend to create safety copies of the ".big" files you are about to change.

Here's a textual version of the steps posted in the video description:

> 1. Download XCC Mixer: http://xhp.xwis.net/
> 2. Install XCC Mixer
> 3. Start XCC Mixer
> 4. Browse to Zero Hour root folder
> 5. Double click LanguageZH.big file
> 6. Find generals.csf file
> 7. Right click it and Extract
> 8. Choose "ZH Root\Data\Language"
> 9. Save to destination
> 10. Launch - XCC String Table Editor - Open
> 11. Select extracted generals.csf, Open
> 12. Select CONTROLBAR
> 13. Select line you want to change
> 14. Click on Edit
> 15. Put new letter behind "&" Symbol for new shortcut
> 16. Apply change by clicking OK
> 17. Save changes to file by clicking OK
> 18. Start game and test changes

Comment: I've gone ahead and pasted in the steps outlined in the video description into your answer. While the video might be more helpful, including a textual summary of the video contents is helpful in the event the video is ever taken down. It's also helpful in the event a user isn't able to view the video for whatever reason. That said, considering this answer is from 3 years ago, I'm sure I'm you already know about all this by now, but just wanted to leave this comment just in case! Cheers!

Comment: @Wipqozn Thank you. That makes sense :)

Comment: it doesn't explain what EXACT line defines the map scroll command